# error when i using cv::merge

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am getting following error while using `cv::merge()` statement to merge two images:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth) in merge, file /home/yasin/ProgramFile/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 950
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>        what():  /home/yasin/ProgramFile/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:950: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge

I tried to solve this problem by searching and using some methods but my effort was not useful.

My methods are:

```
void TakeDFT(cv::Mat&source,cv::Mat&DFTofSource){
    cv::Mat OriginalFloat;
    OriginalFloat.convertTo(source,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    cv::Mat OriginalComplex[2] = {
        OriginalFloat,cv::Mat::zeros(OriginalFloat.size(),CV_32F)
    };
    cv::Mat dftready;
    dftready.convertTo(dftready,CV_32F);
    cv::merge(OriginalComplex,2,dftready);
    cv::dft(dftready,DFTofSource,cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
}
```

and:

```
void TakeDFT(cv::Mat&source,cv::Mat&DFTofSource){
    cv::Mat OriginalFloat;
    OriginalFloat.convertTo(source,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    cv::Mat OriginalComplex[2] = {
        OriginalFloat,cv::Mat::zeros(OriginalFloat.size(),CV_32F)
    };
    cv::Mat dftready;
    dftready.convertTo(dftready,CV_32F);
    std::vector<cv::Mat>array_to_merge;
    array_to_merge.push_back(OriginalComplex[0]);
    array_to_merge.push_back(OriginalComplex[1]);
    cv::merge(array_to_merge,dftready);
    cv::dft(dftready,DFTofSource,cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
}
```

I'm a beginner in opencv and confused.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only declaring OriginalFloat (not defining it), and then you try to convert it (while it's an empty matrix).

I assume what you want to do is rather

```
source.convertTo(OriginalFloat, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
```

You will have the same problem with dftready. What you need to do is either to define its type by creating the matrix: `cv::Mat dftready = cv::Mat dftready(source.size(), CV_32F);`, or simply declaring it `cv::Mat dftready;` and let the `cv::merge` function creating it with the right type.

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenCV 3.0 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge):

> The functions merge merge several arrays to make a single multi-channel array.

Your destination matrix `dftready` is created as one-channel matrix (`CV_32F`) instead of 2-channel matrix with `CV_32FC2`.

Comment: I am tested your solution ,but doesn't work and i get same error (-215) ... .